# Wordpress with Google Tag Manager

Tags: wordpress, google-tag-manager

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8gIH.png)

I have implemented datalayer on my Wordpress Website, but when i track it on Google Tag manager it is showing that view item is triggered multiple time once we press on product category , in addition on view item tab in gets info for another products as shown in the image below how to solve